# Streaming data from url throws Connection Error

Tags: python, python-requests

Code is streaming data from url into file. File is about 500Mb. Data is streamed, because the goal is to use as few memory as possible.

```
        with requests.get(url, stream=True, headers=_headers) as r:
            r.raise_for_status()
            with open(os.path.join(metric_bundle, data_type, data_name+".csv.gz"), 'wb') as f:
                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

From time to time it throws next error

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 380, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: OSError("(104, \'ECONNRESET\')",)', OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')",))
```

header is

```
_headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_token,
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}
```

How to prevent code from throwing this error. Retrying?

Comment: How long does it take the successful ones to complete?

Comment: @Kris 4 minutes or something